# AbstractMethodError in Grails Spring Security

Tags: java, grails, groovy, spring-security

in my Grails 3.3.8 app with

```
  compile 'org.grails.plugins:mongodb'
  compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.3.1"
```

I implemented a custom `UserDetailService`:

```
class MongoUserDetailsService extends GormUserDetailsService {

  static final NO_ROLES = [ NO_ROLE ]

  @Override
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  UserDetails loadUserByUsername( String username, boolean loadRoles = true ) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
    def u = UserAccount.findByUsername username
    if( !u )  throw new UsernameNotFoundException( "User not found: $username" )
    log.info "found user: $u"
    List<GrantedAuthority> roles = loadRoles ? u.authorities : NO_ROLES
    new GrailsUser( u.username, u.password, u.enabled, true, true, true, roles, u.id ) // here the exception thrown
  }

}
```

Upon authenticating I'm getting the exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:310)
    at my.company.security.MongoUserDetailsService$$ESA2Twnm.$tt__mongoUserDetailsService_loadUserByUsername(MongoUserDetailsService.groovy:28)
```

I tried coercing a map as `UserDetails` and instantiating User class, but the same exception is being thrown.

`gradlew depencencies` shows groovy-*:2.5.14 dependencies everywhere.

Now I'm lost...

Comment: Is `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` on purpose? Aren't you persisting `new GrailsUser` in this service? Moreover `new GrailsUser()` seems as the last statement. is it extending `UserDetails` class which should be returned?

Comment: yes, no, yes...

Comment: I have read: `AbstractMethodError usually means that the classpath contains incompatible dependencies.` . have you tried to create a brand new project without any extra dependencies (except spring security), check if it's working fine for your UserDetailService implementation and try adding your dependencies one after another until you find a possible root cause? Try to use the same order of dependencies as your original project.

Comment: turns out, it was an "underwater" clash of Groovy versions and has nothing to do with grails-spring-security... One of my libs had Groovy 3.0.5 and has been smuggled in, despite Grails' Gradle dependency constraints